# Ubuntu 18.04 without graphical desktop is taking 5 min to boot

Tags: 18.04

```
Startup finished in 5min 11.381s (kernel) + 17.186s (userspace) = 5min 28.568s
graphical.target reached after 17.159s in userspace
```

The services are loading quickly but can't figure out why kernel is taking over 5 minutes to boot up.  The machine is 24 core, 64GB RAM fast CPU.  Where to look to find why the kernel is taking so long?

`dmesg` shows only UFW blocks. `syslog` shows this line occassionally
 `ubuntu kernel: [141881.865777] perf: interrupt took too long (5083 > 4933), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39250`

`/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=806f2d97-f0bc-4468-97c8-faca9c935380 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=70f9615c-accc-4a91-8fa8-c8482972fb48 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /mnt/md0 was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=dffbeccd-a777-40f5-8e56-756366ab198f /mnt/md0        ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=63dc9015-84ad-4dbb-a0d9-e3a6653f4e70 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

UPDATE:  removed swap but made no difference

UPDATE:  KVM access to the server was not working.  The hosting provider rebooted KVM.  Right after that the Ubuntu server started to boot in 15 seconds.  Probably a freezing KVM that allows boot access to the server was causing the slow boot issue.

Comment: I would check your your *file system table* (`/etc/fstab`) for entries that don't exist, or cannot be contacted (ie. network that aren't available, or local that have been changed because of format or removal etc). Did you look in `dmesg` for clues?

Comment: You really don't need swap with 64 GB of RAM, so you can disable it.

Comment: swap removed.  But didn't make any noticeable difference.